# Using middleware to add arguments to view functions in django

Tags: python, django, view, middleware

I have a pretty small, basic site with a handful of views. Pretty much all of the views perform some interaction with an external API.

In each view I instantiate an object of my API class, which obviously is not very DRY. I also have a piece of middleware that adds one or two useful variables to the request object (my middleware runs last in the chain).

I was thinking of instantiating my api class in the middleware, and then passing it to each view as an argument, i.e.

```
def my_view(request, my_api_class_instance):
```

and then calling the view from the middleware, something like:

```
def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
    my_api = api(some, args, here)
    response = view_func(request, my_api, *view_args, **view_kwargs)
    return response
```

It seems like a quick and easy way to tidy some code and reduce repetition. Is there anything inherently BAD about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the Django middleware [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/middleware/#process-view), you'll see;

> If **process_view** returns an **HttpResponse** object, Django won’t bother calling any other view or exception middleware, or the appropriate view; it’ll apply response middleware to that HttpResponse, and return the result.

So returning an HttpResponse will skip the execution of other middleware classes below this one which *in general should be avoided* unless your middleware is the last one in **settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES** list.

However, you still can bind your API object to HttpRequest instance passed on to middleware. It is the same approach to what AuhenticationMiddleware does in order to populate request.user.

```
def APIMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        request.api = API(host, port, user, password, extra={"url": request.get_full_path()})
```

Answer (score 2):

you can just change view_kwargs in middleware

```
class SomeMiddleware(object):
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        view_kwargs['my_api'] = api(some, args, here)
        return None

def my_view(request, my_api):
    # you can use you api there
def my_view(request, args, my_api)
    # you can use you api there
```

[document it's there](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process-view)
middleware returns None, Django will continue processing this request, executing any other process_view() middleware.

but, this only applies to every view function can got the keyword argument 'myapi', otherwise will raise the TypeError.

so the best way isn't pass your api by func arguments, like @ozgur pass your api by request.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a middleware but there are two other possibilities too, both more flexible. The first one is to use a decorator and wrap the view:

```
@my_api_init_decorator
def my_view(request, my_api):
    ...
```

This allows you to explicitly select views, check user authorization or permissions before you init your api...

The second solution is to use class based views and create your own view you inherit from.

Comment: This way, developer could end up having to wrap up all views in the app with a new decorator, which is not flexible and generic.

Comment: Depends on your use case. If all views need the api access and it will never change, then go with the middleware. If there are/will be views where you don't need the api access, then it would be better to use one of these possibilities. It is flexible in the way, that you can very easily control which view has the api access and which not. Or you can check for permissions (ot other things) per view before the api initializes (usefull when the api init is an expensive call and you want to minimize these calls).

Comment: The question says: "Pretty much all of the views perform some interaction with an external API.", so middleware should be the preferred approach.